# Are there official rules and formats for small side soccer football without goalkeeper?

Tags: rules, football, fifa

I would like to know are there any official, possibly FIFA, formats and rules of soccer football match that could play without goalkeeper and has each team member on field more than 4 but less than 9 player

What is the dimension of the field? How the size and shape of the goal should be? How the rules differ from 11v11? Are there any special rules given for the lack of goalkeeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of games descended from association football can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_football#Games_descended_from_The_FA_rules). Seems like [Jorkyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorkyball) kind of fits the question specifications, but at the end it's just a fancy name to a football game played 2 vs 2 on a reduced size pitch with no goalkeepers.

There are no types of football which use no goalkeepers that are governed at the highest level as far as I can tell. The other variations of football that governed by FIFA are: [futsal](https://www.fifa.com/futsal/index.html) and [beach soccer](https://www.fifa.com/beachsoccerworldcup/index.html). There are also variations for athletes with a physical disability, like [football 5-a-side](https://www.paralympic.org/football-5-side) or [football 7-a-side](https://www.paralympic.org/football-7-side).

Answer (score 1):

FIFA has no laws for this form of modified game. The closest thing would be futsal which is 5v5 but has many different laws compared to soccer.

If a league is running a competition in the format you mentioned, they would have to create their own laws, just like leagues do for indoor soccer.